# 64bit HashCodes, IEqualityComparer & Intersect/Except

Tags: c#, hashcode, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer

I'm generating 64 bit hashcodes from strings, and storing this value in a database

Is it possible to override GetHashCode with a 64 bit long type instead of 32 byte int?

If this is not possible, is it possible to implement Equals and GetHashCode somewhere else, and still use Except and Intersect?

```
public class RecordComparer : IEqualityComparer<Record>
{
    public bool Equals(Record x, Record y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.RecordHash.Equals(y.RecordHash);
    }

    public long GetHashCode(Record obj)
    {
        return obj.RecordHash;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It is dubious to use hashes for equality due to hash collisions.

Comment: It is for 32 bit hash integers... collisions start to occur after 100,000 records. However the 64 bit hashes guarantees a very very low collision rate.

Comment: "64 bit hashes guarantees a very very low collision rate": yes, they do. But not _equality_. Which is what a correct implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` or `Equals()` needs.

Comment: Please explain what `Intersect` and `Except` you're talking about here, and what they have to do with your question. The only implementations of those operations in .NET will work equally well whether your hash codes are 32-bit or 64-bit, as they don't use the hash code to determine actual equality.

Comment: That make sense. However, for my purposes, a 64 int will be unique enough that I can live with a collision every few trillion records or so. Is it possible to override the GetHashCode to return a 64 bit integer?

Comment: @user1691808: No, you cannot change the return type of `Object.GetHashCode` but does your code even depend on `GetHashCode`. The value returned is mainly used in types like `Dictionary<T>`. .NET never assumes equality based on equality of has codes.

Comment: Basically I will have 2 lists of with 64 bit hash code integers. I need to be able to use Except/Intersect on these 2 lists to find the differences, based on the 64 bit hascode value. As everything stands, IEqualityComparer<T> only works with 32 bit integers.

Answer (score 1):

None of the built-in collections, algorithms and interfaces support 64 bit hash codes. You must build everything yourself. You need a whole parallel infrastructure.

This will likely turn out to be not worth the effort. Rather, use a 32 bit hash code and rely on your equality comparison to make sure that no false matches happen. This is required for correctness anyway.

Maybe this question is based on a misunderstanding:

> Basically I will have 2 lists of with 64 bit hash code integers. I
>   need to be able to use Except/Intersect on these 2 lists to find the
>   differences, based on the 64 bit hascode value. As everything stands,
>   IEqualityComparer only works with 32 bit integers.

Simply treat this hash code as the key in the built-in collections and algorithms. You can process those lists using `Except` just fine.

Comment: I can probably work arround this idea, however my lists are actually of an object, one property being the hash value, the other property being the ID of the record. If I just make a list of long and intersect, I will have to also pull the object list to get the correct record IDs associated to the Except/Intersect results

Comment: There are extension methods called ExceptBy and IntersectBy on the web. They do what you apparently need. If you can't use them implement this algorithm yourself using joins or dictionaries. None of this seems to touch on the issue of hash codes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not care about the possible problems arising from different records having equal hash codes and thus being considered equal even though they are different you can simply implement `RecordComparer` like this:

```
public class RecordComparer : IEqualityComparer<Record>
{
    public bool Equals(Record x, Record y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.RecordHash.Equals(y.RecordHash);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Record obj)
    {
        return unchecked((int) obj.RecordHash);
    }
}
```

`IEqualityComparer<T>` is correctly implemented by returning a 32 bit hash code created by truncating the 64 bit hash code identifying the record.

There is no requirement that `GetHashCode` should return unique hash codes for unequal records. However, avoiding collisions will make generic collections like `Dictionary<Record>` perform better and basing the 32 bit hash code on the 64 bit hash code is probably the best thing to do.

If you look at the source code for `Enumerable.Except` and `Enumerable.Intersect` you can see that they use the internal class `Set<T>` which is some sort of hash table so your implementation of `GetHashCode` can affect the performance of your code but not the correctness (as long as equal records return the same hash code).

Comment: It seems to me the 64 bit value would be converted to a 32 bit before being sent back, which wouldn't really help in my case of intersecting two lists of 64 bit ints for differences. But I've never used unchecked, so my thinking might be incorrect

Comment: @user1691808: `unchecked` is just to avoid any exceptions in case you are compiling your code with `checked` turned on (the default is turned off). The cast basically truncates the 64 bit value to 32 bit and you do not want an `OverflowException` when doing that.